# Java Program using Apache POI giving me weird Exceptions

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, apache-poi

I am having some serious difficulty getting my project off the ground. I have the following code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("src/retestchecker/test_sheet.xlsx"));
//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell x = row.getCell(3);

System.out.println(x);
```

I am getting this error and I am not sure what it means:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at retestchecker.RetestChecker.main(RetestChecker.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

I am using Netbeans and the latest version of Apache POI that was released May 11, 2015.

The line 23 that the error refers to is this line:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems you don't have all the required libraries on the classpath. You might want to try Maven for instance if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the xmlbeans jar (and possibly more)

Apache POI has a [handy page describing all of the components and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), or if you use Maven it's all taken care of for you

In a binary release, you'll find xmlbeans in the `ooxml-lib` subdirectory. Add that, and any other jars [needed for the components you're using](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) to your classpath

Answer (score 1):

This means that the compiler couldn't find a class named org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
You have to find which .jar files of apache poi define it and add them to your project's classpath.